# Symfony2 / FOSUSerBundle Registration Slow

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am about to launch my App and since I am expecting high initial traffic, I did some load tests beforehand. The results are puzzling me quite a bit.

I have used New Relic for the monitoring and I can see that the registration takes some time, especially in the Database. (Here the Analytics):
[image: Performance Tace]

I don't really understand why a simple Insert would take 1,4s.

There is nothing really special in this table. The only thing is a Doctrine array column:
array: Type that maps a SQL CLOB to a PHP object using serialize() and unserialize()

I am just unsure if that is a real database issue or if my code could already cause this.

Comment: did you try using variables instead of ? in the insert values ?

Comment: This is something that my Database abstraction layer provides, this is necessary to cache the queries. Since the query is always the same, only inserted values are different.